# Videos Appearing as Black Boxes in UIImage Snapshots of WKWebView

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, wkwebview

I am captruing the content of  `WKWebView` into a `UIImage` via its `CALayer` by using the following extenstion to `UIImage`:

```swift
extension UIImage {
   class func imageFromLayer(layer: CALayer) -> UIImage {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.bounds.size, layer.isOpaque, 0.0)
      layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
      let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
      return img!
   }
}
```

When I render the captured image to a `UIImageView`, I see everything from the web view in the image view; everything, except videos, whose content instead appears as a black box. I encounter the same problem if I use WKWebView's `takeSnapshot` function or the `drawHierarchy` function of the `UIView` class to capture `UIImage` of the web view. Does anyone know why videos are displayed as black boxes and how one can fix this?

*Update 1:* Additionally, all GIFs in Google Images are frozen until clicked. A GIF can be unfrozen by clicking on it, at which point it gets resized to take up the whole screen and starts looping.

*Update 2:* I have read that the recording software OBS sometimes experiences the same problem with capturing videos when the browser that it is capturing uses hardware acceleration. I also read that `WKWebView` uses hardware acceleration. Is there a way to disable hardware acceleration in `WKWebView` to try this out? Alternatively, does `UIWebView` use hardware acceleration?

*Update 3:* There is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690932/taking-screenshot-of-wkwebview-with-hardware-accelerated-content) that reports a similar issue. The poster reports that all GPU rendered content appears black in his screenshots and he believes that hardware acceleration is causing the issue.

*Update 4:* By using Xcode's "Quick Look" feature I have observed that the layer that is passed to `imageFromLayer` does not contain the videos (i.e. videos are already represents as black boxes in the passed in layer). This makes me think that `WKWebView` does not render videos to the same layer as it renders its other content. It also makes me think that if I could access this hypothetical video layer I would be able to combine the two snapshots to form a snapshot of the entire web view.

*Update 5:* I tried modifying my `imageFromLayer` function to take a `UIView` instead of a `CALayer` so that I could pass `WKWebView` into it directly. The modified version is shown below, but it did not solve the issue of videos not being displayed. Nevertheless, through the use of Xcode's "Quick Look" feature I was able to observe that the videos are already missing in the `UIView` of the passed in `WKWebView` object.

```swift
class func createImage(view: UIView) -> UIImage {
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
   view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
   let rasterizedView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
   return rasterizedView
}
```

*Update 6:* Trying to capture the web view via the `UIWindow` that contains it also results in videos not being captured. I used the below code (note that `keyWindow` is deprecated) and Xcode's Quick Look feature to test this idea.

```swift
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
let windowLayer = window!.layer
```